# Python Importing cx_Oracle ImportError: DLL load failed. It could not be found

Tags: python

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database through python 3.6.1 (64-bit).

- I have installed cx_Oracle-5.3-11g.win-amd64-py3.6-2.exe from the
  url:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.3
- Then i have downloaded the Instant client, and extraced the content to the destination: C:\Python\instantclient_11_2
  url: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
  File1: instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
  File2: instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
  File3: instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
- Then i have added the windows environment variable:
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH : C:\Python\instantclient_11_2
  ORACLE_HOME : C:\Python\instantclient_11_2
  PATH : C:\Python\instantclient_11_2
  PATH : C:\Program Files\Python36\
  PATH : C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\
  TNS_ADMIN : C:\Python\instantclient_11_2

But still i get the error that it can't find the cx_oracle module when i run the following code in python:

> Import cx_oracle

I have tried both 32 bit version of py, oracle client, and cx_oracle

I have also been looking on all similar threads in the forums, and still can't fix the issue. Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Comment: your python version ins 3.6.1, but you installed cx_oracle 3.6.2, try with the 3.6 64 bit

Comment: not sure, but when i go to the website it is listed to be compatible with py3.6. i think the '-' means it covers both 1 and 2. but i might be wrong.

Comment: I however experienced that downgrading py to 3.4 and downloading oracle stuff for 3.4 - it works.. maybe there is some errors with 3.6 version of cx_oracle

Answer (score -1):

Use:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-362/
python-3.6.2-amd64.exe

django 1.11

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.3
cx_Oracle-5.3-11g.win-amd64-py3.6-2.exe

Oracle 11g 11.2.0.1.0

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Install 
instaclient-basic-win-x86-64-11.2.0.1.0
instantclient-sdk-win-x86-64-11.2.0.1.0

Unzip both files in the same folder
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZDDI9HFBIU

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)